# Add Eventlistener to two Canvas elements

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events

I experimented with Canvas and Javascript. I wrote a function to draw a Canvas element with an id and add some event listeners so I can drag the element up and down by holding down the mouse and move her.

My Problem is that when I create a second canvas element with a separate id I can drag it, but the first won't move anymore. This is how I add the event listeners:

```js
canArray.push(canvas);
//alert(canArray.length);

for (var i = 0; i < canArray.length; i++) {
  //alert(canArray[i]);

  updateCanvasRect(canvas);
  canArray[i].addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
  canArray[i].addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
  canArray[i].addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
  canArray[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeave, false);
}
```

Hope you understand my problem and have an idea how I could handle my problem so both Canvas elements will get the event listener!

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/gxt4vnu7/1/
There is a version of my work. You can see I can move the bar up and down by clicking. But when you delete the comment at line 9 and run the code, surprisingly the second bar doesn't work as planed and the first bar doesn't work at all! :(

Comment: Could you share the code you use for moving (the handlers). The snippet wasn't runnable, please set up a working example. The current amount of code doesn't give us much insight..

Comment: I changed the context from global to parameter in every function, but obviously it doesn't work for the first canvas :/ Any ideas? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qw238qxt/ Another case, same problem :/